# Is there an API for Buddhist texts?

Tags: modern-world, media

Does anyone know of an API for Buddhist texts along the same lines as this one for the [Bible](https://bibles.org/pages/api). I do some spare time software projects and I would like to hook up to Buddhist text API just as part of playing around with some new technologies. Currently I'm using the [Google Books](https://developers.google.com/books/) API for it.

What I'm imaging is that one could make a web request to a URL such as http://buddhisttextapi/dhammapada/verse/12 and you would get back the 12th verse of the dhammapada in whatever translation. So for the technically minded I'm interested in some kind of REST API - preferably under active development or at least with some decent documentation.

Many Thanks

Comment: SuttaCentral, for example, uses URLs which look like [https://suttacentral.net/en/sn5.3](https://suttacentral.net/en/sn5.3) ... would that count as an answer or are you looking for something other than that?

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks but not really. That returns HTML which is human readable. You want machine readable so XML or JSON.

Comment: To machine-read any web site, I use Html Agility Pack, which converts an HTML document to XML. Looking at the format of that linked Sutta Central page, for example, I would extract the contents of the `article` element (or `section.sutta` or `div#text` elements).

Comment: @ChrisW I didn't know HAP can convert HTML to XML. +1

Comment: @ChrisW true but I just want the JSON or XML directly. I don't want to use the Agility Pack or any HTML parsing (like what is offered in google books). I'm using node.js and express for the server. The agility pack is purely C# isn't it. But thanks for the thought. The answer below gives a good to be fair so I'm happy with that

Comment: @Crab Bucket, how did suttacentral api work out for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SC has a API. E.g. : https://suttacentral.net/data?suttas=dn1,dn2

Also see: https://discourse.suttacentral.net/t/suttacentral-api-apps/1927/8

Also the data is in Github. E.g. https://github.com/suttacentral/suttacentral-data/blob/master/text/en/pi/su/an/an1/an1.21-40.html

Similarly you can download the whole Access to Insight website as files: http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tech/download/bulk.html